# NuGet ignoring config file

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, continuous-integration, nuget, continuous-deployment

I want to change the default push source on a machine to something other than nuget.org. I've implemented this on my own machine by putting a nuget.config file in %ProgramData%\NuGet, and that's working fine. However, when I try to replicate this on my build server, it seems to be ignoring the config file. I've tried switching it to NuGetDefaults.config (and other variations) and still no luck. Updated nuget.exe to no avail.

Differences between my local setup and the build machine:

- Windows 7 Enterprise vs Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
- Run by Visual Studio (2015) post-build event vs a Windows batch script run by Jenkins
- Project on C drive under user directory vs D drive and not user-specific

Any idea why I can't get things to work? Any steps you can recommend to debugging the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I created the file on the server, despite naming it nuget.config, it still had the Text Document's .txt tacked onto the end behind the scenes. Changed Explorer through the View tab to show file extensions and removed the .txt, and now everything works.